# Public ECR image for aws-cli instead of docker hub amazon https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I am searching for the ECR version for the aws-cli, instead of the one found on docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-cli) to not stress the rate limit imposed upon by docker.
I have searched https://gallery.ecr.aws and cannot find aws-cli by Amazon/AWS, only the one by bitnami.
Does anyone know where to find it, or should I redirect my question elsewhere and if yes, where?

Comment: Why don't you build yourself a simple image that include `aws-cli` installation with your own settings? for example `FROM alpine:3.14`

Comment: I have an image already, but I have to keep it updated. I am unsure, why they are not offering it.